# fopen(files/Camera Roll): failed to open stream: Permission denied | laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Error: - fopen(files/Camera Roll): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have to open  the file from public/files/ and the code : - 
controller

```php
   public function theme_demo($id){
      $view_theme_demo = ThemeUpload::findOrFail($id);
      $myfile = fopen("files/$view_theme_demo->theme_file", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
      echo fread($myfile,filesize("files/$view_theme_demo->theme_file"));
      fclose($myfile);
      return view('pages.theme_demo')->with([
      'zip'  => $zip
      ]);
    }
```

Comment: Use one of the Laravel path helpers such as e.g. [`public_path`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path)

Comment: You have more problems. 1. you are using Relative path to file, which can cause errors. 2. you are echoing from Controller, what it also bad practice.